# Is there a second derivative test in polar coordinates ? How to calculate concavity in the radial direction?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

I searched google for articles talking about second derivative test in polar coordinates and found nothing at all.

Could you please refer me to an article or a book about it?

I'm asking because I want to calculate the concavity of a surface at origin in the $radial$ direction as a function of $\theta$.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to have a discriminant test for polar coordinates, so that you can easily see whether the critical point of a function $f(r,\theta)$ is an extremum or a saddle point.

The transformation of the discriminant to polar coordinates is a straightforward if somewhat tedious exercise.  A direct calculation spawns a great number of terms, most of which conspire to annihilate one another.  The final result can then be written as the determinant of a symmetric matrix,
$$
\Delta(f) = \det\left[
 \begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r^2} & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial r\partial\theta}
 -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\\
 \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \theta\partial r}
 -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta} & \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial\theta^2}
 +\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}
 \end{array}
\right]
$$

Note that the individual entries in the above matrix are ${\it not}$ equal to the corresponding entries in the cartesian version, but the result for the determinant is the same.  In particular, for any twice differentiable function $F(x,y)$, if you feed
$$
f(r,\theta) = F(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)
$$
into the above expression for $\Delta(f)$ and simplify, the result will be
$$
\Delta(f)
=
F_{xx}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)F_{yy}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)-\left[F_{xy}(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)\right]^2,
$$
just as you would wish.

Answer (score 1):

The second derivative test can be used in polar coordinates as well to determine the convexity. Just note that you need to calculate $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}$ in terms of $r$ and $\theta$. Knowing that $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$, one can write:
$$y'=\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{d y}{d \theta}\frac{d \theta}{d x}=\frac{d y/d\theta}{d x/d\theta}=\frac{r\cos\theta+r'\sin\theta}{-r\sin\theta+r'\cos\theta}$$
where $r'$ means $\frac{dr}{d\theta}$. Hence:
$$y''=\frac{d y'}{d x}=\frac{d y'/d\theta}{d x/d\theta}=\frac{r^2+2r'r'-r r''}{(r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta)^3}$$
Now you can use the second derivative test wherever you want. As a side-note there are plenty of online resources about this matter. For example, [this](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section10.02.html) and [this](http://www-math.mit.edu/~djk/18_022/chapter02/section04.html) were among the first results that google gave me.

And another side-note is, you mentioned you want to calculate the concavity of a *surface*. This means you would deal with 3-D polar coordinates, which is much more complex but pretty the same.

Comment: You are right but what I am asking for is second derivative test for $surface$ to calculate the concavity in the $radial$ direction not in $x/y$ directions.

Comment: @MohamedMostafa : I was wondering about the difference between concavity in _radial_ direction and in $x-y$ direction, but couldn't think of any. Can you give a counter-example where these two are different?

Comment: Concavity in x-y direction tells only how the function behave in these two directions only, but what about concavity at 45 degrees? concavity in x-y direction could be used to test extrema of the function but when it fails you can't tell if the point is extreme or saddle. Concavity in radial direction gives all possible directions of concavity so you can know for sure if the critical point is saddle or not.